# Estimating power consumption of GDDR5 chip from data sheet

Tags: power, low-power, sdram

I am trying to better understand the power consumption of [this 8Gb Micron GDDR5 chip](https://static6.arrow.com/aropdfconversion/bdeae9ae3dcde4dff6abcb1f4b567c32c4b0824d/2757328342967568gb_gddr5_sgram_brief.pdf). Specifically, I want to estimate the following:

- **idle**—What is the power consumption when the chip is idling?
- **max activity**—What is the power consumption when the chip is at max activity?
- **low data rate**—What is the power consumption when the chip data rate is low, e.g. at 1.0 Gb/s (the maximum data rate is 6.0-8.0 Gb/s)?
- **low power modes**—"Low power modes" is listed as one of the features and I'm assuming they are referring to the `ABI_n` and `DBI[3:0]_n` pins. What are the power savings there?

Can the above information be gleaned from the data sheet or other online sources?

Comment: It should be possible to get estimates if you have the data sheet and not the data brief, seems like the complete specification is only available on request? All I'm able to find is the data brief which isn't very helpful. Maybe registering on the Micron website is enough to get a data sheet (they advertise maximum visibility of data sheets upon registering...)

Comment: You'll have to contact Micron directly to get a full datasheet and answers to your questions.